# Clone an Java entity object to save in 2 tables same struture

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I have User table and User_Hist table. they are same structure:

```
User (User_ID, Name, Address)
User_Hist (User_ID, Name, Address)
```

when I create the new user, the data will be saved in both tables and if a row on User table is removed, we will update this row by data back-up from User_Hist.
Currently, I'm using the JPA to store into db and BeanUtils.copyProperties to clone data.

```
BeanUtils.copyProperties(user, UserHist);
saveAndFlush(User);
saveAndFlush(UserHist);
```

On Spring, do we have any ways to help store db on multi table ? (without using trigger on db)

Comment: You may use Hibernate Envers. Or otherwise your attempt with copyProperties is good and well on Spring, too.

Comment: This is clear where I prefer to create Triggers to automaticly create/update the history of this line. Don't need to be managed from the back-end at all. Don't know why you excluse those.

Answer (score 0):

I don't thing there is any way to store the same data in two table in on go excluding trigger although you can use one java object to store data in different tables so that you can avoid cloning or copping bean property to different object.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an EntityListener to your User entity 
Just annotate it with

```
@EntityListeners(UserListener.class)
```

and add UserHist saving in the `@PostPersist` methood.

See [the example](http://www.concretepage.com/java/jpa/jpa-entitylisteners-example-with-callbacks-prepersist-postpersist-postload-preupdate-postupdate-preremove-postremove). Read also [this](https://programmingmitra.blogspot.com.by/2017/02/automatic-jpa-auditing-persisting-audit-logs-automatically-using-entityListeners.html) to access EntityManager